# .NET CF Socket receive timeout

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, windows-ce

I'm working on an app for Windows CE 5.0 , by .NET CF 3.5 SP1. i wanna simulate socket receive timeout and wrote some codes :

```
    ...
    AutoResetEvent auto = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    mySocket.BeginReceiveFrom(arrData, 0, 4, SocketFlags.None, ref EP, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), mySocket);
//if (auto.WaitOne(10000,false)) or :
    if (auto.WaitOne())
    {
// program flow never comes here, even after setting signal!
    _log.AppendLine("Message receive success");
    }
    ...
```

and here's my callback method :

```
void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {

            bool b = ((EventWaitHandle)ar.AsyncWaitHandle).Set();
            _log.AppendLine(string.Format("AsyncWaitHandle.Set() called and returned {0}",b));

        }
```

as i tested the app and logged some info, i receive data immediately and 'ar.AsyncWaitHandle.Set()' returns true, but why program flow never ends? what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should pass the WaitHandle i created for example as StateObject parameter to my BeginReceiveFrom method that i can access it later in callback method. i edited my code and it works now. in fact , i think the related samples on the Internet are so weak and terrible.

```
...
EventWaitHandle auto = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset);
auto.Reset();
mySocket.BeginReceiveFrom(arrData, 0, 4, SocketFlags.None, ref EP, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), auto);
if (auto.WaitOne(10000, false))
{
_log.AppendLine("Message lenght receive success");
}
...
```

and

```
void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{

bool b = ((EventWaitHandle)ar.AsyncState).Set();
_log.AppendLine(string.Format("AsyncWaitHandle.Set() called and returned {0}",b));
}
```

Comment: Has your question been answered now? I'm not sure if you need more help with this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `WaitHandle` you set in the event handle is the same as the `auto` you created, and are waiting on. The `BeginReceiveFrom` method returns an `IAsyncResult` object, which contains the handle you are signalling.

Also if data is waiting, the `BeginReceiveFrom` method can be handled synchronously (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iasyncresult.completedsynchronously.aspx). You should probably first check that property before you wait.

Comment: yes u r right. they are not the same. i should pass the WaitHandle i created for example as StateObject parameter to my BeginReceiveFrom method. i edited my code and it works now. i'll put it here. Thanks